# How to get a notification when an entry with certain values becomes available on Hazelcast?

Tags: hazelcast

I would like to register for a certain set of values for any entry's keys can take and get notified when such entry is added. For example, if an entry has keys name, city, country, price, age, etc. and I would like to get notified for only when an entry with name=Bob, city=Chicago is inserted and ignore anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `Predicate` and use it to build a Query Cache. After the construction of query cache, all changes on the underlying `IMap` are immediately reflected to this cache as a stream of events. This cache will be an always up-to-date view of the `IMap` with your query applied. Please see the usage here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#continuous-query-cache

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. So this way I will be able to create a virtual stream per predicate. 

Is there a limit for the number of Predicates I can create? 

I am planning to use this scheme for a messaging system I am architecting and would like to use it as a way to issue a query for any incoming request to collect additional information from other components of the system, and then compute the original request with the answer(s) coming via these one or many `Predicate` streams.

It is ok to retire these `Predicate`s automatically, called evictions I guess in Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Alparslan's answer, when using Predicates, it's a good idea to add indexes (indices?) to the fields you querying on.